Retrieve Only Specified Roles for Users Within Each Team in Laravel
I'm implementing a roles and permissions system that includes both team-specific and user-specific roles. I need to list all teams a user belongs to, along with the roles assigned to the user within each team. The data structure includes:
Table model_has_roles:




Table roles:

For example, if a user with ID 1 should only have roles with IDs 4 and 5 in specific teams, I'd like to ensure only those roles appear in the results.
Additionally, if this user belongs to multiple teams, any roles assigned to the user within each team should be included in the results.
Code Structure
I attempted the following relationships:
Team model:
public function userRoles(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'model_has_roles', 'team_id', 'role_id')->distinct();
}

User model:
public function teams(): BelongsToMany
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Team::class, 'model_has_roles', 'model_id', 'team_id')->distinct();
}

public function teamsWithRoles(): Collection
{
    $this->loadMissing(['teams', 'teams.userRoles']);

    return $this->teams;
}

Current Check
Running the following check:
$user->teamsWithRoles()->pluck('userRoles', 'id')->map(fn($collection) => $collection->pluck('name', 'id'))->dd()

Produces:
{"1":{"4":"user","8":"user"},"2":{"5":"system"}}

Here, the result includes an unexpected role (ID 8). I only want role IDs 4 and 5 to be associated with this user for the specified teams.

"the result includes an unexpected role (ID 8)" - why is it unexpected? at no point do you filter your query on a specific user id. So for team 1 it will load roles (4,4,8,4,8), but distinct will be (4,8) and for team 2 will load roles (5). How do you intend to use this result? what happens when you want to check the roles of multiple users?

you can modify your function to filter only roles of the current user:
public function teamsWithRoles(): Collection
{
    $this->loadMissing(['teams.userRoles' => function ($relation) {
        $relation->where([
            'model_id' => $this->id,
            'model_type' => static::class,
        ]);
    ]);

    return $this->teams;
}

this should also remove the need to apply distinct to the query
